# Mostrar valor columna tabla relacionada

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Cuando escribo:

```
{{ $viaje->cliente }}
```

Me aparece el array con todos los valores de las columnas de la tabla cliente del id el viaje cargado.

Cuando escribo:

```
{{ $viaje->cliente->name }}
```

Me muestra el error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Anteriormente he tenido este mismo problema intentando acceder a tablas relacionadas y lo solucione mediante un foreach, pero en este caso cuando escribo:

```
@foreach($viaje->cliente as $cliente)
{{ $cliente->name }}
@endforeach
```

Me muestra el siguiente error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

La única diferencia con las anteriores tablas es que la relación entre la tabla viajes y la tabla clientes es:

```
public function cliente() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente', 'cli_id');

    }
```

He intentado cambiar la relación entre las tablas a  "return $this->hasMany('App\Cliente');" , pero me genera errores en otras vistas ya creadas que funcionan correctamente.

Añado var_dump($viaje->cliente)

```
C:\wamp64\www\proyecto-laravel\storage\framework\views\81f936806d9158b1066adcc4d976b577e89c991c.php:20:
object(App\Cliente)[268]
  protected 'table' => string 'clientes' (length=8)
  protected 'connection' => string 'mysql' (length=5)
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'keyType' => string 'int' (length=3)
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'withCount' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'exists' => boolean true
  public 'wasRecentlyCreated' => boolean false
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'SIDAC IBERIA' (length=12)
      'apodo' => string 'SIDAC' (length=5)
      'created_at' => string '2019-01-04 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2019-01-04 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'remember_token' => null
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'SIDAC IBERIA' (length=12)
      'apodo' => string 'SIDAC' (length=5)
      'created_at' => string '2019-01-04 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2019-01-04 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'remember_token' => null
  protected 'changes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'casts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'dateFormat' => null
  protected 'appends' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'dispatchesEvents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'observables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'touches' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '*' (length=1)
```

Comment: no puedes cambiar de forma arbitraria la relación de belongs a hasMany, la idea aquí es que nos indiques como esta la cardinalidad de tus tablas, posterior agrega como mandas los datos del Controller a la vista

Comment: ¿podemos ver un dump de `$viaje->cliente`?

Comment: @Shaz Añado var_dump

Comment: Como menciona @shadow , no puedes cambiar sólo porque sí las relaciones, las relaciones de las tablas de tu BD deben de tener una cardinalidad definida, pero bien, ¿podrías agregar el segmento de código en donde se hace uso de `$viaje`? Lo más seguro es que si estás en un bucle, hay un registro el cual no tiene registros relacionados de la tabla `cliente` y cuando imprimes `$viaje->cliente` en la primera iteración si te devuelve el objeto pero hay uno de los que tienes el cual es nulo.

Answer (score 0):

He seguido buscando y he encontrado la manera de acceder a las propiedades del objeto cliente añadiendo el siguiente código a la vista:

```
{{ $viaje->cliente['name'] }}
```

Simplemente hay que indicar entre [''] el nombre de la columna que se quiere mostrar.

Gracias a todos los que se tomaron la molestia de contestar.

Un saludo,